# How A Solr Request Takes Too Much Time

Tags: performance, solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have 3 nodes Solr data center. I am trying to redirect all queries to node1 using solr http api because i think i have problems with node2, node3. I will replace them. I enabled datastax solr slow query metric. I see two main problem.

1. Even though i set `shard.shuffling.strategy=host`

Document says that
host
Shards are selected based on the host that received the query.

and i expect that when request `http://node1:8983/solr/....` , the `coordinator_ip` and `node_ip`  columns in `solr_slow_sub_query_log` table will be the same. When i get the records, i see 80% percentage is `node1`. Is not that wrong? I expect 100% request use `node1`.

2. When i get records from solr_slow_sub_query_log, i see that the rows coordinator_id=node1 and  node_ip=node2ornode3 has too much elapsed_millis such as 1300 seconds even though document says netty_client_request_timeout is 60 seconds.

Comment: If the nodes are in a solr cloud setup (I'm not familiar with Datastax), the nodes can route requests internally as well, meaning that node1 can route a request to node2 for loadbalancing as well. Could that be what you're seeing?

Comment: @MatsLindh DSE does not use SolrCloud

Comment: DSE Solr will still shard out requests to all nodes in the cluster in order to satisfy the replication factor of the keyspace. Theres no point in trying to restrict the query to one node since you may have a partition in cassandra on another node and so Solr needs to do this to execute the "scatter and gather" search.

Comment: @markc what if i need to delete node2 index data and reindex node2. will queries running on  node2 show wrong result?

Comment: when a node is indexing queries should be routed away from it by the shard router